# Biblatex, JEA style

Tags: biblatex

I provide here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,showtrims]{memoir} % for a 4long document
\usepackage{fontspec} % Font selection for XeLaTeX; see fontspec.pdf for documentation
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % to support TeX conventions like ``---''
\usepackage{xunicode} % Unicode support for LaTeX character names (accents, European chars, etc)
\usepackage{xltxtra} % Extra customizations for XeLaTeX
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[style=verbose-   ibid,firstinits=true,sorting=nty,sortcites=true,useprefix=false,isbn=false,maxnames=6,citepages=omit,backend=biber]{biblatex} % originally the style was verbose-ibid
%\usepackage[style=footnote-dw,namefont=smallcaps,firstinits=true,idembib=true,idembibformat=dash,nopublisher=false,edbyidem=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%put commas instead of periods after some elements of the title
%\usepackage{biblatex}%remove �in� in journal articles
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
\ifentrytype{article}{}{%
\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\printtext[parens]{% ADDED
\printlist{location}%
%\iflistundef{publisher}
  %{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
 % {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
%\printlist{publisher}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\usebibmacro{date}%
}%\nopunct% ADDED
\newunit}
%for citing short forms
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
\printnames{labelname}%
\setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
% If article:
\ifentrytype{article}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printfield{volume}}{%
% If incollection:
\ifentrytype{incollection}{%
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \printtext[booktitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}}}{%
% Else:
\printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}}

%for defining shorthands
\defbibcheck{noshorthand}{%
\iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\skipentry}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%journal abbreviation instead of full title
\iffieldundef{shortjournal}
{%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
    {}
    {%
      \printtext[journaltitle]
        {%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
          \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}%
         }%
     }%
}
{\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkcomprange{#1}}

\setcounter{mincomprange}{100}
\setcounter{maxcomprange}{100000}
\setcounter{mincompwidth}{10}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\blx@comprange@check}
{\blx@comprange@comp{#1}{#2}}
{\blx@tempcnta=#1
\divide\blx@tempcnta100
\multiply\blx@tempcnta100
\ifnumequal{\blx@tempcnta}{#1}
 {\blx@range@out@value{#1\bibrangedash#2}}
 {\blx@comprange@comp{#1}{#2}}}
{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange{#1}}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mkcomprange{#1}}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
```

These are the two instances of bibliography I am actually using:

```
@incollection{Leahy.2011c,
author = {Leahy, A.},
title = {'Necho' in Late Period personal names},
pages = {547--573},
bookpagination = {page},
publisher = {Uitgeverij Peeters en Departement Oosterse Studies},
series = {Orientalia Lovaniensia Analecta},
editor = {Aston, D. A. and Bader, Bettina and Gallorini, Carla and Nicholson, Paul and Buckingham, Sarah},
booktitle = {Under the Potter's Tree},
year = {2011},
usera = {Yes},
location = {Leuven},
booksubtitle = {Studies on Ancient Egypt Presented to Janine Bourriau on the Occasion of Her 70th Birthday},
number = {204},
}

@book{Blobaum.2006,
author = {Bl{\"o}baum, A. I.},
year = {2006},
title = {''Denn ich bin ein K{\"o}nig, der die Maat liebt''},
number = {4},
publisher = {Shaker Verlag},
subtitle = {Herrscherlegitimation im sp{\"a}tzeitlichen {\"A}gypten},
location = {Aachen},
series = {Aegyptiaca Monasteriensia},
shorttitle = {Denn ich bin ein K{\"o}nig}
}
```

What comes from the codes above is:

> A.LEAHY,“A mysterious fragment and a monumental hinge.Necho II and Psammetichus II once again”, in: *Verba manent. Recueil d’études dédiées à Dimitri Meeks par ses collègues et amis*, ed. by I. RÉGEN and F. SERVAJEAN, Cenim 2, (Montpellier, 2009), 227–40.
>
> A.I.Blöbaum, *”Denn ich bin ein König,der die Maat liebt”,Herrscherlegitimationimspätzeit-
> lichen Ägypten*, Aegyptiaca Monasteriensia 4, (Aachen, 2006)

I would like the following changes, matching the Journal of Egyptian Archaeology requirements:

> A.I.Blöbaum, *”Denn ich bin ein König,der die Maat liebt”,Herrscherlegitimationimspätzeit-
> lichen Ägypten* (Aegyptiaca Monasteriensia 4; Aachen: 2006)

This means that I would like to get rid of the comma at the end of the title, and put the Series and its number in the round brackets.

Moreover, for a contribution in an edited book, I would like something like that:

> A.LEAHY,“A mysterious fragment and a monumental hinge.Necho II and Psammetichus II once again”, in I. RÉGEN and F. SERVAJEAN (eds),*Verba manent. Recueil d’études dédiées à Dimitri Meeks par ses collègues et amis* (Cenim 2; Montpellier: 2009), 227–40.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You would support potential helpers by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), including the bibliographic data.

Comment: Definitely do as domwass suggested, it will help us. Also, you might want to try and clean up your code for us – any macro that is used for displaying in-text citations is not needed in order to answer your question. In the meanwhile, you may want to start looking at the `standard.bbx` file in your `biblatex` folder: modifying the output of the bibliography is quite easier and more straightforward than what you have asked for so far, even without reading the documentation. Maybe it could get you started with some programming if you feel like it (though some one of us will help, indeed).

Comment: @ienissei Thanks for the comment. I have not cleaned the macros, sorry for that. But I will check the standard.bbx you you told me about. My question at this point, is if I modify it, should I give a new name to it and save the original file with a different name?

Comment: @RobertoGozzoli Yes, definitely. You can modify its macros in your preamble of course, but I daresay it is getting a bit crammed now. So, you should at least copy the file to your `texmf` folder modify it there, this way it will be used over the one in your distribution. Renaming it is a bit trickier as you must also *find*, *rename* and *modify* the files which summon it in your case (`verbose-ibid` and `authortitle`). Or you could simply pack all of your macros in a `.sty` file and load it with `\usepackage`

Comment: And, if you did not have already come across it, you should read the [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The document below demonstrates style edits that will change the format and print order of "by" editors and series titles. For brevity, I carried over only some of the style changes from your MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,firstinits=true,maxnames=6]{biblatex} 

% Put editor string in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Like editor+others but without comma before editor string and dash checks
\newbibmacro*{ineditor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test \ifuseeditor and not test {\ifnameundef{editor}} }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}

% Print editors before "in" title
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
  \usebibmacro{ineditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \clearname{editor}}

% Print series as usual if location is undefined
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iflistundef{location}
    {\printfield{series}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{number}%
     \newunit}
    {}}

% Omit preceding punctuation, print series with location,
%   omit publisher, wrap in parentheses
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \nopunct%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}}%
    \newunit}

% A few other style changes carried over from your MWE
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\newunitpunct}
\renewcommand\mkbibnamelast[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{leahy,
  author = {Leahy, A.},
  title = {`Necho' in Late Period personal names},
  pages = {547--573},
  bookpagination = {page},
  publisher = {Uitgeverij Peeters en Departement Oosterse Studies},
  series = {Orientalia Lovaniensia Analecta},
  editor = {Aston, D. A. and Bader, Bettina and Gallorini, Carla and Nicholson, Paul and Buckingham, Sarah},
  booktitle = {Under the Potter's Tree},
  year = {2011},
  location = {Leuven},
  booksubtitle = {Studies on Ancient Egypt Presented to Janine Bourriau on the Occasion of Her 70th Birthday},
  number = {204}}
@book{blobaum,
  author = {Bl{\"o}baum, A. I.},
  year = {2006},
  title = {``Denn ich bin ein K{\"o}nig, der die Maat liebt''},
  number = {4},
  publisher = {Shaker Verlag},
  subtitle = {Herrscherlegitimation im sp{\"a}tzeitlichen {\"A}gypten},
  location = {Aachen},
  series = {Aegyptiaca Monasteriensia},
  shorttitle = {Denn ich bin ein K{\"o}nig}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{leahy,blobaum,aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics,kant:kpv,hyman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]