# Biblatex: formatting editor in incollection

Tags: biblatex

I need to change the way `@InCollection` entries are printed in the bibliography.  Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone} %
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} %
\usepackage{filecontents} %

\addbibresource{example.bib} %

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@InCollection{lewis16,
author =       {Lewis, David},
title =        {The Paradoxes of Time Travel},
booktitle =    {Science Fiction and Philosophy},
year =         {2016},
crossref =     {schneider16},
pages =        {357--369}
}

@Book{schneider16,
title =        {Science Fiction and Philosophy},
year =         {2016},
editor =       {Schneider, Susan},
publisher =    {Wiley},
location =     {New York}
}

\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{pages}{#1} %
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} %

\begin{document}

\nocite{lewis16}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Currently, it gives me:

> Lewis, David (2016). “The Paradoxes of Time Travel”. In *Science Fiction and Philosophy*. Ed. by Susan Schneider. New York: Wiley, 357–369.

But I need to have:

> Lewis, David (2016). “The Paradoxes of Time Travel”. In Schneider, Susan, ed. *Science Fiction and Philosophy*, 357-369. New York: Wiley.

And `Schneider, Susan and Other Editor, eds.` for multi-editor volumes.

I've looked at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/adapting-typesetting-of-editor-field-information-in-verbose-style/224314#224314), but it does not explain how to reformat the name(s) of editors.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an up to date `biblatex` version (that is, the current version: 3.11), you can use [`biblatex-ext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) which extends the standard styles, offering some extra rings and bells, including the option `innamebeforetitle`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone} %
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ext-authoryear,innamebeforetitle=true]{biblatex} %
\usepackage{filecontents} %

\addbibresource{example.bib} %

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@InCollection{lewis16,
author =       {Lewis, David},
title =        {The Paradoxes of Time Travel},
booktitle =    {Science Fiction and Philosophy},
year =         {2016},
crossref =     {schneider16},
pages =        {357--369}
}

@Book{schneider16,
title =        {Science Fiction and Philosophy},
year =         {2016},
editor =       {Schneider, Susan},
publisher =    {Wiley},
location =     {New York}
}

\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{pages}{#1} %
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} %

\begin{document}

\nocite{lewis16}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I have 3.7, but I can update.  However, where is biblatex-ext documented?  For instance, a search in the manual for 3.11 for innamebeforetitle yields no results.  Where can I learn about the new options?

Comment: @GrB You can find it here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext and, once you update, probably also with `texdoc biblatex-ext`. One advice though, even though an update is usually welcome, it might break things sometimes, so please proceed with care if you are on a deadline.

Comment: If, for any reason, you don't want to update at the moment, you may want to look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/105447

Comment: Thanks, that's a great tip.  [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173653) worked best for me.

Comment: We don't need to load `\usepackage{biblatex-ext}`? Can we just go ahead and use it with biblatex as if it was part of it?

Comment: @thymaro As it is the case with many contributed styles, it is enough to call the `style=ext-authoryear` within the call to `biblatex` itself. That's the recommended way to use the styles of `biblatex-ext` in its documentation.