# Modifying biblatex @inbook bibliography, remove Ed. by and change ordering

Tags: biblatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Biblatex, JEA style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47707/biblatex-jea-style)

I'm using bib latex for managing my bibliography, I did some adjustments and so far I'm quite pleased with it. When I add an @inbook source to my bib-file I get the result in the bibliography like this:

> Badelt, C., More-Hollerweger, E. (2007): Ehrenamtliche Arbeit im
>   Nonprofitsektor. In: Handbuch der Nonprofit Organisation - Strukturen
>   und Management. Ed. by C. Badelt, M. Meyer, R. Simsa. 4. Aufl.
>   Stuttgart: Schäffer-Poeschel, 503–531.

I want to change it to this:

> Badelt, C., More-Hollerweger, E. (2007): Ehrenamtliche Arbeit im
>   Nonprofitsektor. In: C. Badelt, M. Meyer, R. Simsa.: Handbuch der
>   Nonprofit Organisation - Strukturen und Management. 4. Aufl.
>   Stuttgart: Schäffer-Poeschel, 503–531.

The "Ed. by" should be gone and the author(s) should be placed before the booktitle.

This is my configuration:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex8,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    hyperref=true,
    maxbibnames=9,
    maxcitenames=3,
    firstinits=true,
    isbn=false,
    url=false
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} % no prefix «S.» before page in citation
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace} % colon instead of dot before title
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}} %et al. instead of u.a.
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography

%comma between volume and number

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{{#1},} % journal title with comma

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\addperiod} % italic title with period

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{booktitle}{#1} % booktitle of inbook is printed as normal text

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % italic title of journal article

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % sorting

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space} % remove "and" before last author in bibliography, place right before \bibliography

\bibliography{bibliography}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This was previously addressed among a laundry list of style customizations [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47780/4483).