# Citing @inbook with biblatex: how to put authors/editors before book title?

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to cite a chapter from a book using biblatex:

```
@inbook{ , 
  crossref{X}
}   
@book{X,
}.
```

This produces a citation in this layout:

```
    Authors. Title. [...] In: Title. Authors. [...]
```

I need to swap the Title and Authors in the "In:" reference, i.e. to get

```
    Authors. Title. [...] In: Authors. Title. [...]
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The solution depends on the bibliography style you're using. If it is based on the standard style `standard.bbx`, the relevant part of the `@inbook` driver is:

```
\usebibmacro{in:}%
\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
```

For `@incollection` and `@inproceedings`:

```
\usebibmacro{in:}%
\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
```

and

```
\usebibmacro{in:}%
\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
```

The bibliography macros `bybookauthor` and `byeditor+others` are defined in `biblatex.def`.

To change the order of the title and name list after `in:`, you could redefine each of these drivers and use variants of `bybookauthor` and `byeditor+others` to suppress the "by" strings.

Alternatively you can redefine the `in:` macro to print and clear the name list. This approach has been [previously applied](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47707) for the `byeditor` case. Here's an example addressing the name list printed by either `byeditor+others` or `bybookauthor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
  \ifnameundef{bookauthor}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
        \clearname{translator}}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
        \clearname{editor}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
       {}
       {\printnames{bookauthor}%
        \clearname{bookauthor}}}%
  \newunit\newblock}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{inbook,
  crossref = {book},
  author = {Smith, John},
  title = {Inbook Title}}
@book{book,
  author = {Doe, John and Brown, Bob},
  title = {Book Title}}
@incollection{incollection,
  crossref = {collection},
  author = {Smith, John},
  title = {Incollection Title}}
@collection{collection,
  editor = {Doe, John and Brown, Bob},
  translator = {Smith, Jane},
  title = {Collection Title}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{inbook,incollection}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As similar questions are asked rather frequently, please consider to incoroarate your answer code into a new package option (e.g. `editorbeforetitle`, default `false`) that solves this for all standard styles.

Comment: @lockstep I am not sure about that as there are many package options already. Regarding this "in title" business I'd sooner omit `in:` from the `@article` driver. But please feel free to submit feature requests at github. It'd be good to get your feedback on style improvements.