# Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

For a stylesheet I am following, I need to move the names of the editors of a book before the book title. In `biblatex`, the default behavior is to print `Ed. by` followed by the names. A similar question has been asked before ([Citing @inbook with biblatex: how to put authors/editors before book title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122218/citing-inbook-with-biblatex-how-to-put-authors-editors-before-book-title)), but the only answer given differs in many respects from what I need, and I don't know how to modify it to suit my needs here.

In the MWE, the printed result is:

> Lennon, John (1965). This is my article in this book. In *A book with articles*. Ed. by Paul McCartney, John Lennon, George Harrison & Richard Starkey. Liverpool: Cavern Club. 65-87.

Whereas I need it to be:

> Lennon, John (1965). This is my article in this book. In Paul McCartney, John Lennon, George Harrison & Richard Starkey (Eds.), *A book with articles*. Liverpool: Cavern Club. 65-87.

Notice the uppercase `E` in `Eds.` (which should be `Ed.` in the case of a single editor) and the comma following it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, maxnames = 99]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} % use '&' before last author in citations and bibliography
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} % remove colon after "In:" for articles in books
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1} % no word 'pages' for articles in the bibliography (print as is)
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{title}{#1} % no quotes for article titles (print as is)
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}} % colon between volume and page ranges for journal articles, period plus space for articles in books

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{lennon1965,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    BOOKTITLE = "A book with articles",
    EDITOR = "Paul McCartney and John Lennon and George Harrison and Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "This is my article in this book",
    YEAR = "1965",
    LOCATION = "Liverpool",
    PAGES = "65--87",
    PUBLISHER = "Cavern Club"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Shameless plug: The styles of the [`biblatex-ext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) bundle have a slightly more sophisticated version of this implemented as an option. Load `ext-<standardstyle>`, e.g. `ext-authoryear-comp` and set the option `innamebeforetitle` to `true`.
>
> ```
> \documentclass[british]{article}
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage{babel}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
>
> \usepackage[backend=biber,
>   style=ext-authoryear, innamebeforetitle=true]{biblatex}
>
> \DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
> \DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
>
> \DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
> \DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
>
> \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
>
> \begin{document}
> \cite{sigfridsson,gaonkar:in,westfahl:space,vizedom:related}
> \printbibliography
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> [image: Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar (2001). ‘On Alternative Modernities’. In: Dilip Parameshwar Gaonkar (ed.). Alternative Modernities. Durham and London: Duke University Press, pp. 1–23. isbn: 0-822-32714-7.//Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//Vizedom, Monika B. and Gabrielle L. Caffee (trans.) (1960). The Rites of Passage. University of Chicago Press. Trans. of Arnold van Gennep. Les rites de passage. Paris: Nourry, 1909.//Westfahl, Gary (2000). ‘The True Frontier. Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in American Science Fiction Films’. In: Gary Westfahl (ed.). Space and Beyond. The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction. Westport, Conn. and London: Greenwood, pp. 55–65.]

This is really where `biblatex` is not that flexible.

We can use `xpatch` to patch the drivers for `@inbook`, `@incollection` and `@inproceedings`

```
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}
```

We also redefine `byeditor:in`

```
\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \addspace\bibsentence%
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \printunit{\addcomma\space}}}
```

and a new name format

```
\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{first-last}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, maxnames = 99]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{title}{#1}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{lennon1965,
  author    = {John Lennon},
  booktitle = {A book with articles},
  editor    = {Paul McCartney and John Lennon and George Harrison and Richard Starkey},
  title     = {This is my article in this book},
  year      = {1965},
  location  = {Liverpool},
  pages     = {65--87},
  publisher = {Cavern Club},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{first-last}

\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \addspace\bibsentence%
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \printunit{\addcomma\space}}}

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}



\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As with Guido's example, your example flips the order of the names of the first editor from first-last to last-first. Can that be avoided? Also, the abbreviation for editor ``(Eds.)`` should be in parentheses with an uppercase ``E``. And there should be a comma following it, i.e. ``(Eds.),``.

Comment: @Sverre Sure! Have a look at the edit. I'm afraid doing things like this are somewhat hard to achieve in `biblatex`, it might warrant a new style.

Comment: And what about ``(Eds.),`` instead of ``(eds.).``? ``:)``

Comment: @Sverre See the edit. (I suspect you already have code to add the parentheses.)

Comment: Uh, no ... I see Guido has ``\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}``. Should I use that? I'm not sure where to put it, though.

Comment: When I compile this, it prints ``eds.``, not ``Eds.`` as indicated in your picture. Also, there shouldn't be a final comma after the last name of the editors.

Comment: @Sverre Try again (I have re-edited the answer).

Comment: Works like a charm now.

Comment: It did feel a little guilty answering [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433566/105447) today. That is a shameless "plug". ;)

Comment: How would this be adapted to `biblatex-ext`? As you said, we have `innamebeforetitle`, but how to change `〈, Ed.〉` to `〈 (Ed.)〉`? And can this also be done for direct `@collection` entries?

Comment: I found some relevant things digging around in `biblatex.def`: could we add  `\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}` and `\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` to the preamble? It seems to work but I am always anxious about these kinds of hacks... :)

Comment: @svenper `editortypedelim` and `editortype` are indeed what you are looking for, but maybe you also want to change `translatortypedelim` and `translatortype`. As far as I am concerned those are not hacks, but the intended interface.

Comment: @moewe Excellent move that you're expanding biblatex with more options. Biblatex would be a lot more user friendly if it allowed for more features to be specified as package options.

Comment: @Sverre Well, `biblatex-ext` has some new options, but not everything it does is implemented as an option. I personally think that not everything needs to be an option. If there are other clear and usable interfaces like `\DeclareFieldFormat` that do the same thing, then that is enough for me. Some more complex things would just get messy as options.

Comment: May I know which part to change to `eds`? I want `eds` instead of  `(Eds.)`

Answer (score 6):

Guidos way, or - without another package, but with a lot of more code lines - you can change the bibliography-driver for `@incollection` from `standard.bbx`, to display the data in your wanted order; change the `byeditor+others`-macro from `biblatex.def` to put parencites around the editor data; and change the `editorstrg` from `biblatex.def` to use the capitalized version `\bibcpstring` instead of `\bibstring`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, maxnames = 99]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} % use '&' before last author in citations and bibliography
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} % remove colon after "In:" for articles in books
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1} % no word 'pages' for articles in the bibliography (print as is)
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{title}{#1} % no quotes for article titles (print as is)
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}} % colon between volume and page ranges for journal articles, period plus space for articles in books

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{lennon1965,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    BOOKTITLE = "A book with articles",
    EDITOR = "Paul McCartney and John Lennon and George Harrison and Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "This is my article in this book",
    YEAR = "1965",
    LOCATION = "Liverpool",
    PAGES = "65--87",
    PUBLISHER = "Cavern Club"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{editorstrg}{%from biblatex.def
  \printtext[editortype]{%
    \iffieldundef{editortype}
      {\ifboolexpr{
         test {\ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}}
         or
         test {\ifandothers{editor}}
       }
         {\bibcpstring{editors}}%changed
         {\bibcpstring{editor}}}%changed
      {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{editortype}}
         {\ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}}
            or
            test {\ifandothers{editor}}
          }
            {\bibcpstring{\thefield{editortype}s}}%changed
            {\bibcpstring{\thefield{editortype}}}}%changed
         {\thefield{editortype}}}}}


\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%from biblatex.def
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \addspace%added
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%added
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%from standard.bbx
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%changed
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%changed
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%changed
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** fixed the issue of multi-volume (with `maintitle`) and single editor.

A possibility is to abuse the biblatex `in:` macro to to format and print the information as desired.

```
\xpatchbibmacro{editorstrg}{\bibstring}{\bibcpstring}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{editorstrg}{\bibstring}{\bibcpstring}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{
  \ifentrytype{incollection}{%
  \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{first-last}
  \printtext{In}
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \addspace 
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}% 
    }%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}
  \clearfield{maintitle}
  \clearfield{booktitle}
  \clearfield{volume}
  \clearfield{part}
  \clearname{editor}
  }
  {}%
}
```

In this case the "simple" `in:` contains the directives to print the editors and the book title.

The tricks are: (1) use a guard, `\ifentrytype{incollection}`, to restrict the modification to the  specific entrytype; (2) delete the content of the fields `booktitle` and `editor`, thus they are no longer a available in the rest of directive in the driver for `incollection`, and (3) define a new directive to switch last name and first name for the editors: this can be specifying that `editor` is an "alias" for the predefined name format `first-last`, i.e., `\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{first-last}`.

Notice that the excellent and convenient `xpatch` package (i.e., include `\usepackage{xpatch}`) is used to modify how the biblatex string editor(s) is printed. Notice that we need to patch it twice one: the first for the plural version, and the second for the singular case (only one editor).

Here is the outcome:

[image]

Comment: In your example, the order of the names of the first editor is flipped from first-last to last-first.

Comment: I overlooked that issue. I just changed it.

Comment: When there is only one editor, your code will print ``(ed.),`` instead of ``(Ed.),`` (i.e. it should have a capital ``E``).

Comment: Also, I've noticed that because of the way ``booktitle`` is included here, the code will print the title of a volume (i.e. ``booktitle``) immediately after ``(Eds.),``. But this is where the main title should be ...

Comment: @Sverre fixed the issues.

Comment: It still prints ``(ed.),``. It now also prints the volume number of books twice, so that it says ``In XX (ed.), maintitle. Vol. 1: booktitle. Vol 1. Place: Publisher. xxx-xxx``.