# Enable "firstinits" in biblatex only for editors

Tags: biblatex

`biblatex` has an option `firstinits` which will abbreviate first and middle names in the bibliography. Is there any way to limit this behavior for the `editor` field only, so that it doesn't abbreviate names in the `author` field?

In the example below, the author should appear as `Lennon, John`, but the editors should appear as `P. McCartney, J. Lennon, G. Harrison, and R. Starkey`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, maxnames = 99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{lennon1965,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    BOOKTITLE = "A book with articles",
    EDITOR = "Paul McCartney and John Lennon and George Harrison and Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "This is my article in this book",
    YEAR = "1965",
    LOCATION = "Liverpool",
    PAGES = "65--87",
    PUBLISHER = "Cavern Club"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name format used there is `byeditor`, so  just go with

```
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{first-last-inits}

\DeclareNameFormat{first-last-inits}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, maxnames = 99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{lennon1965,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    BOOKTITLE = "A book with articles",
    EDITOR = "Paul McCartney and John Lennon and George Harrison and Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "This is my article in this book",
    YEAR = "1965",
    LOCATION = "Liverpool",
    PAGES = "65--87",
    PUBLISHER = "Cavern Club"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{first-last-inits}

\DeclareNameFormat{first-last-inits}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What I feared would happen did happen: This doesn't work together with your solution to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173638/move-names-of-editors-followed-by-ed-eds-and-a-comma-before-title-in-biblate. If put together, no abbreviations occur.

Comment: @Sverre It does: I have `\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{first-last}` there, change that line to `\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{first-last-inits}`.