# Remove period from biblatex entry when there is no editor

Tags: biblatex

Following suggestions by @moewe in the questions [Enable "firstinits" in biblatex only for editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173780/enable-firstinits-in-biblatex-only-for-editors) and [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173638/move-names-of-editors-followed-by-ed-eds-and-a-comma-before-title-in-biblate), I have the code you see below. The problem here is that it prints a superfluous period after `In` when the collection has no editor, as seen in the `Brekke` entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} % remove colon after "In:" for articles in books

%% Abbreviate first names of editors
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{first-last-inits}
\DeclareNameFormat{first-last-inits}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
%%

%% Move names of editors before the book title, and add "(Eds.)"
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{first-last-inits}
\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \addspace\bibsentence%
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \printunit{\addcomma\space}}}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor}}
  {}{}
%%

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{brekke1881,
    AUTHOR = "K. Brekke",
    BOOKTITLE = "Indbydelsesskrift til den offentlige examen i juni og juli 1881 ved Aars og Voss's latin- og realskole",
    TITLE = "Bidrag til dansk-norskens lydl{\ae}re",
    YEAR = "1881",
    LOCATION = "Kristiania",
    PAGES = "1--66",
    PUBLISHER = "W. C. Fabritius"}
@INCOLLECTION{jahr2007,
    AUTHOR = "Ernst H{\aa}kon Jahr",
    BOOKTITLE = "{\AA} sj{\aa} samfunnet gjennom spr{\aa}ket",
    EDITOR = "Gunnstein Akselberg and Johan Myking",
    TITLE = "Bruk av omgrepa 'standardtalem{\aa}l', 'normalisering' og 'knot' for {\aa} skildre spr{\aa}ktilh{\o}va i Noreg i dag",
    YEAR = "2007",
    LOCATION = "Oslo",
    PAGES = "93--98",
    PUBLISHER = "Novus"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to follow the suggestion by @Guido (also to my question [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173638/move-names-of-editors-followed-by-ed-eds-and-a-comma-before-title-in-biblate)), and use the code below. The problem here is that the first names of the editors are not abbreviated (naturally enough, since I didn't ask for it in connection with that question).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} % remove colon after "In:" for articles in books

%% Move names of editors before the book title, and add "(Eds.)"
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{editorstrg}{\bibstring}{\bibcpstring}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{
  \ifentrytype{incollection}{%
  \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{first-last}
  \printtext{In}
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \addspace 
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}% 
    }%
  \printfield[book]{booktitle}
  \clearfield{booktitle}
  \clearname{editor}
  }
  {}%
}%%

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{brekke1881,
    AUTHOR = "K. Brekke",
    BOOKTITLE = "Indbydelsesskrift til den offentlige examen i juni og juli 1881 ved Aars og Voss's latin- og realskole",
    TITLE = "Bidrag til dansk-norskens lydl{\ae}re",
    YEAR = "1881",
    LOCATION = "Kristiania",
    PAGES = "1--66",
    PUBLISHER = "W. C. Fabritius"}
@INCOLLECTION{jahr2007,
    AUTHOR = "Ernst H{\aa}kon Jahr",
    BOOKTITLE = "{\AA} sj{\aa} samfunnet gjennom spr{\aa}ket",
    EDITOR = "Gunnstein Akselberg and Johan Myking",
    TITLE = "Bruk av omgrepa 'standardtalem{\aa}l', 'normalisering' og 'knot' for {\aa} skildre spr{\aa}ktilh{\o}va i Noreg i dag",
    YEAR = "2007",
    LOCATION = "Oslo",
    PAGES = "93--98",
    PUBLISHER = "Novus"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

So my question is: How can I modify the suggestion by @moewe to get rid of the unwanted period in case of missing editors, or how can I modify the suggestion by @Guido to abbreviate the first names of editors?

Comment: If you want to continue using my modifications, the problem you're facing seems to be at first glance of the same kind like [When author field is empty, do not put colon after prenote in authortitle-comp](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196318/35864). I'm guessing a `\printunit` for `\intitlepunct` in the `in:` bibmacro might help: `\renewbibmacro*{in:}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}`. (I will investigate this properly tomorrow though.)

Comment: If you prefer to use Guido's solution, changing the line `\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{first-last}` to `\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{first-last-inits}` and copying `\DeclareNameFormat{first-last-inits}{\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}` to that document should help (untested, but I should think it does the  job). That is, you should be able to apply the answer to [Enable “firstinits” in biblatex only for editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173780/35864) here as well, but the name format in question is `editor`, not `byeditor` (so we have to change that).

Comment: @moewe I followed your suggestion for modifying the suggestion by @Guido. It works, but now I notice that his code prints ``(ed.),`` with a lowercase ``e`` instead of ``(Ed.),`` when there is only one editor. I've put a comment about that to his answer.

Comment: @moewe I've also noticed that @Guido's code inappropriately prints the title of the volume directly after ``(Eds.),``, where rather the main title should be. I'll await the fix for your own code, then ``:)``.

Comment: It seems my first guess about what to do to fix my modification was not at all far off, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix my code, you can modify the `in:` bibmacro to

```
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}
```

that is, we use `\printunit` ([a explanation as to why we need to use `\printunit` can be found in this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196318/35864)).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} % remove colon after "In:" for articles in books

%% Abbreviate first names of editors
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{first-last-inits}
\DeclareNameFormat{first-last-inits}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
%%

%% Move names of editors before the book title, and add "(Eds.)"
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{first-last-inits}
\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \addspace\bibsentence%
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \printunit{\addcomma\space}}}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor}}
  {}{}
%%

%% this is to fix the punctuation after "In"
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}
%%

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{brekke1881,
    AUTHOR = "K. Brekke",
    BOOKTITLE = "Indbydelsesskrift til den offentlige examen i juni og juli 1881 ved Aars og Voss's latin- og realskole",
    TITLE = "Bidrag til dansk-norskens lydl{\ae}re",
    YEAR = "1881",
    LOCATION = "Kristiania",
    PAGES = "1--66",
    PUBLISHER = "W. C. Fabritius"}
@INCOLLECTION{jahr2007,
    AUTHOR = "Ernst H{\aa}kon Jahr",
    BOOKTITLE = "{\AA} sj{\aa} samfunnet gjennom spr{\aa}ket",
    EDITOR = "Gunnstein Akselberg and Johan Myking",
    TITLE = "Bruk av omgrepa 'standardtalem{\aa}l', 'normalisering' og 'knot' for {\aa} skildre spr{\aa}ktilh{\o}va i Noreg i dag",
    YEAR = "2007",
    LOCATION = "Oslo",
    PAGES = "93--98",
    PUBLISHER = "Novus"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using `\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}` (as you [do here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199301/35864)), the fix would obviously be `\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}}\printunit{\intitlepunct}}}`.

Comment: I was just about to ask that :)