# Change separator for articles in journals without volume number (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{number}}{}} % don't print issue for article entries
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}} % don't print "in" for articles
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}} % colon between volume and page ranges for journal articles, period plus space for articles in books
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1} % no word 'pages' for articles in the bibliography (print as is)

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{jensen1916,
    AUTHOR = "Alfred Jensen",
    TITLE = "Bemerkninger til dagligtalen i Kristiania",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Maal og Minne",
    YEAR = "1916",
    NUMBER = "1--2",
    PAGES = "60--89"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bibliographic entry is an article in a journal that doesn't use volume numbers (because it issues one volume each year, so the year itself is sufficient information). The code above will print a colon separator between the name of the journal and the page range. I think this looks weird.

[image]

In such cases I'd prefer either white space:

> Jensen, Alfred (1916). "Bemerkninger til dagligtalen i Kristiania". *Maal og Minne* 60-89.

or a comma plus a space:

> Jensen, Alfred (1916). "Bemerkninger til dagligtalen i Kristiania". *Maal og Minne*, 60-89.

How can I achieve this, so that it prints a colon when the journal has a volume number, but white space or comma plus white space when there is no volume number?

Comment: You do realise though that you do clear the `number` field for article, so in your bibliography *no* entry has a `number` field (`\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{number}}{}`). So do you just want a comma for `@article`s instead of a colon (or the period)?

Comment: @moewe Yes, I included the code where I'm clearing the ``number`` field in case that should become relevant. But, I don't clear the ``volume`` field. I just want a comma if the ``volume`` field is empty. (The ``number`` field is what's normally called 'issues').

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I confused `number` and `volume`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can flesh out the logic in `\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}}` a bit more to

```
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {\addcomma\space}
       {\addcolon}}
    {\addperiod\addspace}}
```

This prints a comma if the entry is an `@article` without a volume, prints a colon, if we have an `@article` with a volume and a full stop otherwise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{number}}{}} % don't print issue for article entries
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}} % don't print "in" for articles
 % colon between volume and page ranges for journal articles, period plus space for articles in books
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1} % no word 'pages' for articles in the bibliography (print as is)

\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {\addcomma\space}
       {\addcolon}}
    {\addperiod\addspace}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{jensen1916,
    AUTHOR = "Alfred Jensen",
    TITLE = "Bemerkninger til dagligtalen i Kristiania",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Maal og Minne",
    YEAR = "1916",
    NUMBER = "1--2",
    PAGES = "60--89"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{angenendt,jensen1916}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is that like you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{number}}{}} % don't print issue for article entries
    \renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}} % don't print "in" for articles
    \renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}} % colon between volume and page ranges for journal articles, period plus space for articles in books
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1} % no word 'pages' for articles in the bibliography (print as is)

 \renewcommand\bibpagespunct{\iffieldundef{volume}{\addcomma\space}{\addcolon\space}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{jensen1916,
    AUTHOR = "Alfred Jensen",
    TITLE = "Bemerkninger til dagligtalen i Kristiania",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Maal og Minne",
    YEAR = "1916",
    NUMBER = "1--2",
    PAGES = "60--89"}
@ARTICLE{Ricoeur:2000ga,
    AUTHOR = {Ricœur, Paul}, 
    TITLE = {{L'écriture de l'histoire et la représentation du passé}},
    JOURNAL = {AHESS},
    YEAR = {2000},
    VOLUME = {55},
    NUMBER = {4},
    PAGES = {731--747},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, because this simply undoes my own ``renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}`` where I make sure that a colon is printed between the volume number and the page range. I only want to remove the colon if there is no volume number. Your ``\renewcommand\bibpagespunct{\addcomma\space}`` won't print a colon anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean you want a colon if there's a volume number and a comma or nothing if there's none?

Comment: Yes. The question I posed was "How can I achieve this, so that it prints a colon when the journal has a volume number, but white space or comma plus white space when there is no volume number?".

Comment: @Sverre: see my updated answer.