# biblatex inbook custom page number postion

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I borrowed the following code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173778/4821).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, maxnames = 99]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{title}{#1}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{lennon1965,
  author    = {John Lennon},
  booktitle = {A book with articles},
  editor    = {Paul McCartney and John Lennon and George Harrison and Richard Starkey},
  title     = {This is my article in this book},
  year      = {1965},
  location  = {Liverpool},
  pages     = {65--87},
  publisher = {Cavern Club},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{first-last}

\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \addspace\bibsentence%
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \printunit{\addcomma\space}}}

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}



\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It gives the following output:

[image]

Whereas I need it to be:

> Lennon, John (1965). This is my article in this book. p. 65-87. In Paul McCartney, John Lennon, George Harrison & Richard Starkey (Eds.), *A book with articles*. Liverpool: Cavern Club.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your MWE ends quite abruptly. Is there anything missing? Is it any different from the code in the answer you linked to?

Comment: My bad @moewe, please see edits.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `xpatch` you can just go on to patch the drivers even further

```
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}{}
```

you also need

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, unpublished]{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace\midsentence}}
```

for the page format instead of

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}}
```

Comment: Thanks @moewe for your answer. Your answer needs some changes for required style. I need `p. 65-87` rather than `Pp. 65-87` and require `(Eds.)` rather than `Ed. by`. Any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 I already get "Eds." if I combine the code with what you have in your question already.  You can use `\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace\midsentence}}` to not capitalise the "pp." after the full stop.