# Customising @inbook or @incollection bibliography entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, harvard-style

I'm very new to LaTeX, only started coding last weekend. I've learned the basics of `bibtex` and switched to `biblatex` to use for my bibliography.

I've been fighting my way through tutorials trying get my own version of the `harvard-style`. I need it to be `authoryear` backended with `bibtex`. I've formatted the `@article` to my liking, but I've been stumbling over the `@inbook` and `@incollection` formatting. If somebody could help me reorder the reference and format some delimiters, it would be great.

I need those to look as such:

> •  Smith, M. P. & Wu, C., 2000. The geology and genesis of the Bayan Obo Fe–REE–Nb deposit: a review. In: Porter, T.M. (Ed.), *Hydrothermal Iron Oxide Copper–Gold and Related Deposits: a Global Perspective*. Australian Mineral Foundation, Adelaide, pp. 271–281.

Thus far my code returns this (the 2 relevant `@inbook`s are #11 and #13):
[image]

MWE of my preamble thus far

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}

  \usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
      {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \usepackage[polish, english]{babel}
  \usepackage{enumitem} % listing package

  %Referencing Style
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{colorlinks = true, citecolor = blue} % recolors hyperlinks

  \usepackage
  [backend=bibtex,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
  maxcitenames=2, % sets limit for et al in citations
  maxbibnames=99, % frees up limits to authors listed in references
  giveninits=true, % initialise each author
  sorting=nyt, % sort by name, author and publication title
  hyperref=true]{biblatex} % citation hyperlinks

  \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\enumerate{}
      {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endenumerate}
  {\item}

  %Corrections to referencing style

  \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{{#1}} % * clears formatting of publication titles
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot} % italicised journal titles

  \renewbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
      \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
           \printfield{volume}%
           \printfield{number}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
           \printfield{eid}} % changed volume-number-pages layout

     \renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon} % colon between volume numbers and pages
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}} % parentheses around volume number

     \DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace} % parentheses bracket around Ed.

     \DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
\usebibmacro{bibindex}%
\usebibmacro{begentry}%
\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
    \newunit
\printlist{language}%
   \newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
\newunit\newblock % <- change
    \printfield{chapter}
\DeclareFieldFormat[chapter]{
\usebibmacro{in:}%
\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}% 
\newunit\newblock 
\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
   {\printfield{isbn}}
     {}%
    \newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
   \newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
\usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
   \iftoggle{bbx:related}
     {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
     {}%
\usebibmacro{finentry}}

  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % puts given names after surname
  \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
  \DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
  \DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}%emboldens volume #
  \renewbibmacro{in:}{}

  \newcommand{\biband}{\ifcurrentname{labelname}{\bibstring{and}}{\&}} % changes citation 'and' to ampersand
  \renewcommand*\finalnamedelim{ \& } % references delimiter becomes ampersand
  \renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space} % adds comma between cited author and year

\addbibresource{Bib/References.bib}

  %Paragraph indentation
  \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}

\begin{document}
```

And my `.bib` file:

```
@Article{Salvi1996,
  author  = {Stefano Salvi and Anthony E. Williams-Jones},
  title   = {The role of hydrothermal processes in concentrating high-field strength elements in the Strange Lake peralkaline complex, Northeastern Canada},
  journal = {Geochimica et Cosmochimica Acta},
  year    = {1996},
  volume  = {60},
  number  = {11},
  pages   = {1917-1932},
  }

@InBook{Smith2000,
  chapter   = {The geology and genesis of the Bayan-Obo Fe-REE-Nb deposit: a review},
  pages     = {271-281},
  title     = {Hydrothermal iron-oxide, copper-gold and related deposits: a global perspective},
  publisher = {Australian Mineral Foundation},
  year      = {2000},
  author    = {M. P. Smith and C. Wu},
  editor    = {Porter, T.M.},
  address   = {Adelaide},
}

@Article{Smith2007,
  author    = {M.P. Smith},
  title     = {Metasomatic silicate chemistry at the Bayan Obo Fe{\textendash}{REE}{\textendash}Nb deposit, Inner Mongolia, China: Contrasting chemistry and evolution of fenitising and mineralising fluids},
  journal   = {Lithos},
  year      = {2007},
  volume    = {93},
  number    = {1-2},
  pages     = {126--148},
  month     = {jan},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.lithos.2006.06.013},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
}

@InBook{Wu1996,
  chapter   = {Rare earth deposits in China},
  pages     = {281–310.},
  title     = {Rare Earth Minerals: Chemistry, Origin and Ore Deposits},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall},
  year      = {1996},
  author    = {C. Wu and Z. Yuan and G. Bai},
  editor    = {A.P. Jones and F. Wall and C.T. Williams},
}

@Article{Yang2004,
  author    = {Xue-Ming Yang and Le Bas, M.J.},
  title     = {Chemical compositions of carbonate minerals from Bayan Obo, Inner Mongolia, China: implications for petrogenesis},
  journal   = {Lithos},
  year      = {2004},
  volume    = {72},
  number    = {1-2},
  pages     = {97--116},
  month     = {jan},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.lithos.2003.09.002},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
}

@Article{Zhang2017,
  author    = {Shuan-Hong Zhang and Yue Zhao and Yongsheng Liu},
  title     = {A precise zircon Th-Pb age of carbonatite sills from the world's largest Bayan Obo deposit: Implications for timing and genesis of {REE}-Nb mineralization},
  journal   = {Precambrian Research},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {291},
  pages     = {202--219},
  month     = {apr},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.precamres.2017.01.024},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
}
```

I need:

1. To remove the 'Chap.' prefix when `chapter` is printed. Just to have an unformatted title.
2. Have `booktitle` go after the 'In:' and the editor names. It'd be great if it was italicised.
3. Have 'Ed. (or Eds, if several editors are named) precede the `booktitle`)
4. Have the remaining information like `publisher` come after these.
5. To have `pp.` visible before the pages for `@inbook` and not for other references where `volume` and `number` are defined.

Sorry if there's something I haven't provided. I tried looking up the previous questions, but it seems to me preferences on formatting of these are countless and it's difficult to dislodge the principle driving `biblatex` from other answers. I mostly end up copying somebody else's code, often without being able to tell ins and outs of it all.

Hope someone could help! Thanks!

PS - if anybody by a chance has an idea how to format the bibliography in `authoryear` style so that the `enumerate` labels are indented to be almost within the page margin instead of squeezing the text into the middle of the frame, that'd be of big help as well!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please note that you have a much better chance of getting good answers quickly if you only ask about one thing per question (however related the several issues here may be). That way you don't risk scaring away those who only have solutions to some of your desiderata. Keeping several requests separate also helps keeping the site relevant for other people as well. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864

Comment: Ad 1) and 2) The chapter title of an `@inbook`/`@incollection` should be given in the `title` field, not in `chapter` (`chapter` should just contain the chapter number). The title of the book/collection should go into `booktitle` and not `title`.

Comment: Ad 3) and 4) This is possible, but requires changes to the driver. You already modify the `inbook` driver (I haven't had a closer look at the code, maybe that is no longer necessary once you fix the issues mentioned above?), but some more work would be needed. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/35864

Comment: Ad 5) Maybe just replace `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}` with `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}`?

Comment: Not sure about your PS. Please ask a new question with more explanations what you mean about that if you are interested in a solution-

Comment: @moewe thanks for your help, I'll be sure to follow the guidelines.

Ad 1 & 2 - this worked. I am using JabRef as a BibTex reference generator and manager, and its default @inbook entry format had `chapter` and `title` fields only. I've managed to edit that successfully!
Ad 3 & 4 - yes, I will need to change the driver it seems as I do want the 'Ed.' in a bracket before the `booktitle`.

Ad 5 - this worked fine, but now conflicts with:
` \renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon} ` 
which I intended to separate `number` and `pages` in article references

I'll address the PS later

Comment: You may want to check that you are using JabRef in `biblatex` mode and not in BibTeX mode (you can see the mode in the window title and can switch modes in the "File" menu under "Switch to <other> mode").

Comment: You can also define `\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addcomma\space}}`.

Comment: Ah, sure. What specifically does it change in JabRef?  I've changed the setting, but not sure what exactly it affects.
And that command suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure, I don't really use JabRef. I suspect it changes the available entry types and fields. I was surprised that your JabRef only showed `chapter` and `title` and not `booktitle` for `@inbook`/`@incollection` entries, so I thought it might have to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases in which you currently employ the `@inbook` entry type, you really ought to be employing the `@incollection` entry type. Moreover, as was already noted by @moewe in his comments, you should change the `title` fields to `booktitle` and the `chapter` fields to `title`.

```
@incollection{Smith2000,
  author    = {M. P. Smith and C. Wu},
  title     = {The geology and genesis of the Bayan-Obo Fe-REE-Nb deposit: a review},
  editor    = {Porter, T. M.},
  booktitle = {Hydrothermal iron-oxide, copper-gold and related deposits: a global perspective},
  year      = {2000},
  pages     = {271--281},
  publisher = {Australian Mineral Foundation},
  address   = {Adelaide},
}

@incollection{Wu1996,
  author    = {C. Wu and Z. Yuan and G. Bai},
  title     = {Rare earth deposits in China},
  editor    = {Adrian P. Jones and Frances Wall and C. Terry Williams},
  booktitle = {Rare Earth Minerals: Chemistry, Origin and Ore Deposits},
  year      = {1996},
  chapter   = {11},
  pages     = {281--310},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall},
  series    = {Mineralogical Society Series},
  number    = {7},
}
```

Comment: Cheers for replying!
Any particular reason why I should use `@incollection` rather than `@inbook`? Is it to do with the default arrangement of fields in either of those?

Comment: @Wolfe79 There is a difference between `@book` and `@collection` that carries through to `@inbook` and `@incollection`. A `@book` is usually a work written in its entirety by a set of authors who are jointly responsible for the complete work. The `biblatex` documentation explains "A [...] book with one or more authors where the authors share credit for the work as a whole." A `@collection` is a, well ... collection, of works by several authors. The complete work is curated, compiled and edited by a team of editors. ...

Comment: ... The `biblatex` docs have "A [...] collection with multiple, self-contained contributions by distinct authors which have their own title. The work as a whole has no overall author but it will usually have an editor. " The editors' names are usually associated with the whole `@collection`, but they need not have authored a significant part of the book (save for maybe a short introduction). If a work explicitly mentions the authors of each chapter and there is little overlap between the authors of each chapter and the complete work has an editor, it's probably a `@collection`.

Comment: For many intents in purposes `biblatex` will still give acceptable results if you mix up `@incollection` and `@inbook` (I just tested the two entries here with `style=authoryear` and the results in the bibliography were the same for `@inbook` and `@incollection`), but there are some subtle differences and it is a good idea to pick the right entry type for the job.