# Biblatex: Modifying 'Ed. by' to (ed.) in book chapters plus slight changes

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

I am following the Manchester Harvard referencing style and is trying to recreate its formatting. Somehow my current code isn't following what I've desired. I'm quite new to LaTeX so it'd be greatly appreciated if someone can help.

This is my code for demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,giveninits=true,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test.bib}

%Last-First name order
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
% Put editor string in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
% Print editors before "in" title
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \clearname{editor}}

\begin{document}

test \cite{Coxall1999} 
\cite{EducationalRole1999}
\cite{HG1999Diversity}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The exported references are shown as below:

> Coxall, H. (1999). “Museum Text as Mediated Message”. In: ed. by Hooper-Greenhill, E. *The Educational Role of the Museum*. 2nd. London: Routledge, pp. 215–222.

> Hooper-Greenhill, E. (1999a). “Museums and Cultural diversity in Contemporary Britain”. In: ed. by Hooper-Greenhill, E. *The Educational Role of the Museum*. 2nd. London: Routledge, pp. 288–294.

> Hooper-Greenhill, E., (ed.) (1999b). The Educational Role of the Museum. 2nd. London: Routledge.

I want the editor fields in the  `incollection` entries (first two) to be the same as the `collection` one (the last one). On top of that, I want the editor to be followed by a comma:

> Hooper-Greenhill, E. (1999a). “Museums and Cultural diversity in Contemporary Britain”, in Hooper-Greenhill, E. (eds.) The Educational Role of the Museum. 2nd. London: Routledge, pp. 288–294.

Is there anyway I can fix this? Apologies if this is asked somehow, but I couldn't figure out how I can incorporate the `renewcommands` and `macro` commands into my case.

FYI: the following is what `test.bib` contains. I exported the entries from Zotero.

```
@incollection{Coxall1999,
    location = {London},
    edition = {2nd},
    title = {Museum Text as Mediated Message},
    pages = {215--222},
    booktitle = {The Educational Role of the Museum},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    author = {Coxall, Helen},
    editor = {Hooper-Greenhill, Eilean},
    date = {1999},
}

@incollection{HG1999Diversity,
    location = {London},
    edition = {2nd},
    title = {Museums and Cultural diversity in Contemporary Britain},
    pages = {288--294},
    booktitle = {The Educational Role of the Museum},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    author = {Hooper-Greenhill, Eilean},
    editor = {Hooper-Greenhill, Eilean},
    date = {1999},
}

@collection{EducationalRole1999,
    location = {London},
    edition = {2nd},
    title = {The Educational Role of the Museum},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    editor = {Hooper-Greenhill, Eilean},
    date = {1999},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Use of `\bibliography` is somewhat deprecated under biblatex. I'd replace `\bibliography{test.bib}` with `\addbibresource{test.bib}`.

Comment: @Mico I've just updated, thanks for the suggestion. I stuck with `\bibliography` cuz `\addbibresource` somehow used to crash my entire PDF rendering. It's not happening anymore so I'll convert back to `\addbibresource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not patch into the `in:` bibmacro to print the editor name before the `booktitle`. Instead I suggest you use `biblatex-ext`'s `innamebeforetitle` option. See [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/35864) for more details.

In fact the MWE from [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/35864) already comes pretty close to what you need, we just need to redefine `innametitledelim` and modify `in:` so that we get a comma before the "in".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\addspace}


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Coxall1999,
  title    = {Museum Text as Mediated Message},
  pages    = {215--222},
  author   = {Coxall, Helen},
  crossref = {EducationalRole1999},
}
@incollection{HG1999Diversity,
  title    = {Museums and Cultural diversity in Contemporary {Britain}},
  pages    = {288--294},
  author   = {Hooper-Greenhill, Eilean},
  crossref = {EducationalRole1999},
}
@collection{EducationalRole1999,
  location  = {London},
  edition   = {2},
  title     = {The Educational Role of the Museum},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  editor    = {Hooper-Greenhill, Eilean},
  date      = {1999},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

test \cite{Coxall1999} 
\cite{EducationalRole1999}
\cite{HG1999Diversity}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Hooper-Greenhill, E. (1999a). “Museums and Cultural diversity in Contemporary Britain”, in: Hooper-Greenhill, E. (ed.) The Educational Role of the Museum. 2nd ed. London: Routledge, pp. 288–294.]

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you!! I'm aware of [the thread you've mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173638/move-names-of-editors-followed-by-ed-eds-and-a-comma-before-title-in-biblate), but I couldn't wrap my head around editing the commands and my deadline for the assignment is very close, so I got desperate and asked. Thanks again!