# Bibliography: Achieving custom bibliography style

Tags: biblatex

I need to set up `biblatex` to obtain the following citation style:

Book:
1. Doe, J.: Book Title. Publisher, Location (date)

Article:
1. Doe, J.: Title. Journal. Number (Issue), pp. pages (year)

Chapter:
1. Doe, J.: Chapter Title. In: DoeEditor, J. (eds.) Book Title, pp. pages. Publisher, Location (year)

inProceedings:
1. Doe, J.: Title. In: Proceedings Title, pp. pages. Location (year)

This is as far as I've been able to come:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric, 
            backend=biber,
            firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, book, incollection, report]{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[proceedings, inproceedings]{maintitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1\adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings, incollection]{booktitle}{#1\adddot}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield[parens]{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
}

\begin{document}
Examples \cite{Doe2014} \cite{Doe2016} \cite{Doe2017} \cite{Doe32015}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the output is:
[image]

My questions are:

- How can I put the year as the field and use ( ) in all entry types?
- How can I remove the pp. from the pages field?
- How can I remove the " " from the inProceedings title?
- How can I reformat the editors field in the book chapter to get it closer to what I need?

Bib file sample:

```
@Book{Doe2017,
  author    = {Doe, Jhon},
  title     = {A Book Title},
  year      = {2017},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  location  = {Some Location},
}

@Article{Doe2016,
  author  = {Doe, Jhon and Doe2, Jhon2},
  title   = {Some journal article},
  journal = {Fancy Journal},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
}

@InCollection{Doe32015,
  author    = {Doe3, Jhon3},
  title     = {A book chapter},
  booktitle = {A book title},
  year      = {2015},
  editor    = {Editor1, Name and Editor2, Name2},
  publisher = {Some publisher},
  location  = {Some location},
  pages     = {54-82},
}

@InProceedings{Doe2014,
  author    = {Doe, Martha},
  title     = {A conference paper},
  booktitle = {Fancy Conference Proceedings},
  year      = {2014},
  location  = {Touristy Location},
  pages     = {1-10},
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is a Q&A site where we prefer to ask only one question per question. If you ask more questions you risk people not answering because they know only partial solutions or you risk getting solutions that don't address everything you look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric, 
            backend=biber,
            firstinits=true]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Doe2017,
  author    = {Doe, Jhon},
  title     = {A Book Title},
  year      = {2017},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  location  = {Some Location},
}

@Article{Doe2016,
  author  = {Doe, Jhon and Doe2, Jhon2},
  title   = {Some journal article},
  journal = {Fancy Journal},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
}

@InCollection{Doe32015,
  author    = {Doe3, Jhon3},
  title     = {A book chapter},
  booktitle = {A book title},
  year      = {2015},
  editor    = {Editor1, Name and Editor2, Name2},
  publisher = {Some publisher},
  location  = {Some location},
  pages     = {54-82},
}

@InProceedings{Doe2014,
  author    = {Doe, Martha},
  title     = {A conference paper},
  booktitle = {Fancy Conference Proceedings},
  year      = {2014},
  location  = {Touristy Location},
  pages     = {1-10},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location}{publisher}}
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location}{institution}}
\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location}{organization}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{issue}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printfield{issue}}}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}
\newbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printdate}


\begin{document}
Examples \cite{Doe2014} \cite{Doe2016} \cite{Doe2017} \cite{Doe32015}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And have a look at [Citing @inbook with biblatex: how to put authors/editors before book title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122218/35864) and [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/35864) for the editor order.